# Rotate aromatic ring

Tags: chemfig

I'm writing the Eriochrome black T structure

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
    \chemfig{*6(=-*6(-(-N(=[:-90]N (-[:-90]*6(-=-=-=)) ))=(-OH)-=(-SO^{-}_{3})-=)--=(-HO)-)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I rotate by 30° the aromatic ring at very bottom? The one bound to the last nitrogen atom from top to bottom

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'rotating by 30 degrees'? I don't suppose you mean to change the angle of the N-N-C bond?

Comment: Solved: `\chemfig{*6(=-*6(-(-N(=[:-90]N (-[:-90]([::-30]*6(-=-(*6(-=-=--))=-(-OH)=))) ))=(-OH)-=(-SO^{-}_{3})-=)--=(-O_{2}N)-)}  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
\chemfig{*6(=-*6(-(-N(=[:-90]N (-[:-90]([::-30]*6(-=-(*6(-=-=--))=-(-OH)=))) ))=(-OH)-=(-SO^{-}_{3})-=)--=(-O_{2}N)-)}
```

[image]